# Get form builder to write out product.name not just in the input field

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I list out 'product.name' on to the physical page using formbuilder? It works fine for the input field but I want to write the physical words in the first td:

```
<table class="editPackagesGeneralTable" formArrayName="products">
  <tr><th class="first">Product / Gift</th><th>Description</th><th>Cost</th><th class="last">Quantity</th></tr>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let product of myForm.controls.products.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i"><td>{{product.name}}</td><td>{{product.description}}</td><td>{{product.unitCost}}</td><td><input type="hidden" formControlName="id" /><input type="text" formControlName="name" /></td></tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Here is my typescript:

```
this.myForm = this.fBuilder.group({
          products: this.fBuilder.array([])
      });

      this.httpService.getExtrasList()
          .subscribe((res) => {
              this.items = res.json();
              console.log(res.json());

              this.items.forEach(element => {
                  (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('products')).push(this.fBuilder.group({
                      id: [element.id],
                      name: [element.name]
                  }));
              });

          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

product.name is a `FormGroup` instance, I guess `{{product.controls.name.value}}` should work.

Comment: I've amended my question to include the typescript. How would I modify that and would I need to change anything on the template?

Comment: oh sorry I didn't get that. This answer is irrelevant. `{{product.name.value}}` should work. Does it ?

Comment: Aw I tried that but I got an error "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".
Many thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: `{{product.controls.name.value}}` product is a `FormGroup`

Comment: Yes that's perfect thanks so much :) Formbuilder hurts my head haha